# Is there a standard method in Ruby to prepend and/or append a string onto each of an array of strings?

Tags: ruby

Is there a standard method in Ruby to prepend and/or append a string onto each of an array of strings?

```
listOfnames = [ 'john', 'dave', 'joe' ];    
mrNames = prependToAll('Mr. ', list of names);
```

resulting in  `[ 'Mr. john', 'Mr. dave', 'Mr. joe' ]`

Is there a version to do so in place?

Or is there a standard way for some easy `each` to replace array entries in the array being iterated over?

Comment: Clear and succinct statement of question, but camel-case variable and method names grate (not Ruby convention).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
listOfnames.map {|name| "Mr. " + name}
```

If you need to edit the `listOfnames` variable, use the destructive version of `map`:

```
listOfnames.map! {|name| "Mr. " + name}
```

Comment: yep - of course I should have found that :) But it's a big world out there :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is `prepend`, but not for an array.

```
%w[john dave joe].map{|s| s.prepend("Mr. ")}
# => ["Mr. john", "Mr. dave", "Mr. joe"]
```

Comment: And there is `append`(if he want to know)

Answer (score 1):

Same result using `Array#product`

```
["Mr. "].product(listOfNames).map(&:join)
```